# Spray to Akka HTTP migration: spray.can.client.request-timeout

Tags: spray, akka-http

I'm migrating an application from Spray to Akka HTTP. In the config, I have:

```
spray {
  can {
    client.request-timeout = infinite
  }
}
```

What is the equivalent config for Akka HTTP? It appears that `request-timeout` is now only available on `server`, and not `client`.

See https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/master/akka-http-core/src/main/resources/reference.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Akka-HTTP docs (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/client-side/connection-level.html#timeouts)

> Currently Akka HTTP doesn’t implement client-side request timeout
>   checking itself as this functionality can be regarded as a more
>   general purpose streaming infrastructure feature.
>
> It should be noted that Akka Streams provide various timeout
>   functionality so any API that uses streams can benefit from the stream
>   stages such as idleTimeout, backpressureTimeout, completionTimeout,
>   initialTimeout and throttle. To learn more about these refer to their
>   documentation in Akka Streams (and Scala Doc).

Essentially the choice is left to the user to add timeout control to their client-side stream. For instance, in the example shown in [the docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/client-side/connection-level.html#opening-http-connections) you could add a `completionTimeout` stage to achieve this

```
  val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] =
    Source.single(HttpRequest(uri = "/"))
      .via(connectionFlow)
      .completionTimeout(5.seconds)
      .runWith(Sink.head)
```

And note that if you're after `infinite` timeout (as per your Spray config), that will come for free by not adding any timeout stage.

Answer (score 0):

```
akka.http {
  server {
    idle-timeout = infinite
  }
  client {
    idle-timeout = infinite
  }

  host-connection-pool {
    idle-timeout = infinite
  }

}
```

You can choose client section.